# maxi and min times to calculate the Fibonacci numbers for six seperate runs at n

Tags: c++, recursion, iteration, fibonacci, timing

The wording for this problem has me completely confused.  I know how to get "timing" using `GetTickCount()` but I have to repeat the calculation 6 times for each N and I have to have 6 different N and the results have to be reported in one table as max an min times.  It seams to me as though this is not feasible because the run time for one N is not going to be the run time for another N.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Ill post the original question below.

**EDIT*:  My own Frazzled brain was over complicating    the problem!  I got it figured out now Thanks to everyone who took time to try and help out!**

'Your task is to find the maximum and minimum execution times of the Fibonacci number computation routines for six separate, unique runs at each value of n. NOTE: do not use the tail recursion implementation.'

I was thinking of perhaps storing the average run time values in arrays and then sorting those arrays to get the min and max and doing that 6 different times for both the min and max for iterative and recursive but that takes something like 24 arrays which just seems pointless.

Comment: So what exactly is the issue? This seems extremely clear to me, unlike your explanation which is all over the place.

Comment: If im using 6 different n values how can I say that the max and min times for one arbitrary value of n can be applied to another value of n.  If i'm misunderstanding the question then I'm wrong but the way the original is worded makes it sound like that is what I have to do.

Comment: "I was thinking of perhaps storing the average run time values in arrays..." - You don't need to store anything besides the min and max corresponding to a given N, and those only until you finish the six runs and report the results. How you establish the initial values of min and max are up to you. When finished with the six runs for a given N, report the resulting min and max and move on to the next N. no arrays are needed.

Comment: I still don't get the issue, so my explanation will probably sound confusing to you too since it's the same thing that's said in the text of your problem: for each `n` you care about, run `fib(n)` 6 times getting 6 durations, and print the minimum and maximum value for each. And no, you don't need any arrays or sorting or whatever other nutso thing you're imagining...

Comment: You were correct it's as you said my own hairbrained feeling was making me overcomplicate the problem.  It's been a long day haha!  Thanks for commenting on the question though.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yep that's exactly what i'm gonna do!  Thanks!  It's the end of the week before spring break here and I've had exams going onnalmost endlessly it seams so i'm a little fried! haha but thanks for the commenting on the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each input N, you need to calculate Fibb(N) six times, and display the minimum and maximum of those times.  You display one minimum per N, and one maximum per N.  Does it help to imagine that there are 100 N, and each one is calculated 6 times?  You'd expect to see 100 minimums and 100 maximums.

For many simple competitions or homework, it looks vaguely like this:

```
while(std::cin >> N) {
   int duration[6] = {};
   int result = 0;
   for(int i=0; i<6; ++i) {
       auto start = GetTickCount();
       int result = Fib(N);
       auto end = GetTickCount();
       duration[i] = end-start;
   }
   int max = std::max_element(std::begin(duration), std::end(duration));
   int min = std::min_element(std::begin(duration), std::end(duration));
   std::cout<<"Fib("<<N<<")="<<result<<" max="<<max<<" min="<<min<<'\n';
}
```

Comment: OK great that does makes sense I was leaning in that direction but the professors example only show one min and one max value so I was getting really confused is there a better way than doing it with multiple arrays or the like?

Comment: Actually I just answered my question my professor meant for each value of n within the n=45 limit. Thank You anyway for helping me sort out my thoughts its the last day of the week  before spring break here and ive just been all over the place!  Thank You! (all mark as answered as soon as the time limit goes away)

Comment: I was thinking about it as doing runs at Fibb(50), Fibb(60) and so on then averaging all of them out some way and trying to apply those max and min times to the professor's Fibb(45).

Comment: @Scymantic: Those would (as you say) be incompariable values, don't do that.